# JSON schema validation for dictionary

Tags: python, json

It is probably a simple question but I can’t get my head around it.

What would be a valid `json schema` to validate dictionary (object) like this:

```
{“1”: "2020-07-02", “2”: "2020-07-03",  etc...etc...etc...}
```

Where key is a string representation of a positive integer (1 to infinity, no floats) and value is a valid
`ISO date`. Max length -`30`.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific with respect to what things you want to be validated? I.e. should keys be converted to numbers? Do you just want dates truncated? Some examples of what should / should not work would be helpful.

Comment: Did not understand what you mean by `valid json schema to validate dictionary`. Can you please explain a little what you want ?

Comment: [`jsonschema`](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is meant to validate JSON, not dicts

Comment: https://json-schema.org/ describes a standards to validate json schema. I mean nothing should be converted, but just each key:value pair should be validated to coincide following standard. key - positive integer (not zero), value -ISO date